# ApplicationError: LinkId(s) specified in request are not available

Tags: here-api

I'm using the HERE Route Match Extension API for matching GPX Data to a route. Afterwards, I am using the road links from the matched route for querying the Routing API. This worked perfectly some weeks ago; strangely I am now getting this error for some of the road links from the Route Match Extension API (response from the Routing API):

```
"_type": "ns2:RoutingServiceErrorType",
"type": "ApplicationError",
"subtype": "LinkIdNotFound",
"details": "LinkId(s) specified in request are not available",
"additionalData": [
    {
    "key": "LinkId[0]",
    "value": "-1224766809"
    }
]
```

In the response from the Route Match Extension API, the road link definitely exists:

*{"confidenceValue":0.6,"elevation":188.39999999999998,"headingDegreeNorthClockwise":10000.0,"headingMatched":118.0,"lat":49.67599245719612,"latMatched":49.67605,**"linkIdMatched":-1224766809**,"lon":10.035531716421247,"lonMatched":10.03558,"matchDistance":8.36,"matchOffsetOnLink":0.6588415883643146,"minError":1000000.0,"routeLinkSeqNrMatched":178,"speedMps":0.0,"timestamp":1532677148000}*

Here is an example query link for the above error: https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=geo!49.77763,9.95697&waypoint1=link!-1224766809&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&app_id=devportal-demo-20180625&app_code=9v2BkviRwi9Ot26kp2IysQ&representation=linkPaging&language=de-de&returnElevation=true&maneuverAttributes=position%2Clength%2CtravelTime%2CstartAngle&instructionFormat=text&routeAttributes=waypoints%2Csummary

What's going on here? Is this just a temporary issue, since it used to work some weeks ago?

Comment: What is the usecase for you to query with the linkId rather than using lat and lon directly? It is always a good idea to use lat,long because there could be changes in linkId. Also, please provide your routing api query used which led to the above error for further support.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport I just added the respective query link to the description. I'll have to check whether working with the coordinates instead of the linkid works for me. However, I'm not saving the ids - they are reused right after the Route Match API call, so I suppose there shouldn't occur an error. This error occurs in quite a lot cases now, in many regions and countries. If it helps, I can also share the original GPX file, from which the linkids are generated in the first place.

Comment: Instances where map versions of RME and routing api are different can lead to this error as well. I see that routing api is using map version: 8.30.88.155. Check if it is the same with RME response you got. Paste the gpx file if yes.

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport In the RME response, the map version is "LATEST". So that could indeed be the problem. How can I force a specific version for both APIs?

Comment: Routing api and extensions api map release cycles are different and you wont be able to change them. It is better to use the lat, lon rather than relying on link id for your usecase.  Using the lat, long from your rme response I get a different link id in routing api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underlying map release for RME and routing api could be different which leads to link id in both not matching. It is recommended to use lat, long for the routing api. 
Routing api and extensions api map release cycles are different and you wont be able to change them. It is better to use the lat, lon rather than relying on link id for your usecase.  Using the lat, long from your rme response I get a different link id in routing api. `https://route.cit.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?waypoint0=geo!49.77763,9.95697&waypoint1=geo!49.67599245719612,10.035531716421247&mode=fastest%3Bcar%3Btraffic%3Aenabled&app_id=<>&app_code=<>&representation=linkPaging&language=de-de&returnElevation=true&maneuverAttributes=position%2Clength%2CtravelTime%2CstartAngle&instructionFormat=text&routeAttributes=waypoints%2Csummary`

Comment: Thank you. So I'll try to change my code accordingly.

Comment: One more question: the whole reason why I'm doing these two API calls is that I need some more information for the road links from the matched GPX, like speed limit. Is there a better way to use RME and get the link details along with the response?

Comment: You can refer to our examples sites on the various possibilities to retrieve speed information https://tcs.ext.here.com/examples/ (search for speed)